# Zend_Mail:: Is there any way to add a recipient using the format: "Name <email>"?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

The reason I ask is because I want to have one editable field where users can enter email addresses and optionally, the name of the email address holder as well.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$info = "<someguy@email.com>";
preg_match('/^(.+?)?<(.+?)>$/',$info,$matches);
$mail->addTo($matches[2], ($matches[1] != '' ? $matches[1] : 'Unknown');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('test@example.com', 'Test');
```

[Zend_Mail addTo()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.adding-recipients.html)

Comment: And the moral of the story is always check the APIdoc.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the replies.  I probably just worded my question incorrectly.  I have an input of say "John Doe <johndoe@email.com>", and I want to be able to add this recipient to the Zend_Mail Object.  I'm guessing I'll have to do something like Korvin Szanto replied with, some sort of regex parsing?  I was hoping I could just set the recipients like $zendMail->setTo($toString);